# How to bind an IValueConverter in Linq to convert the properties

Tags: c#, linq, expression, ivalueconverter

How can I convert the property value to the value the user see?

Example:

```
PropertyValue = 0
TextBox.Text = "zero"
Converter convert from 0 --> "zero"
```

UserInput for filtering:   value="zero"

==> the where clause "value=\"zero\"""

but in my linq I get the PropertyValue 0 compared with userInput "zero"

I have extracted the binded value converters to an array. so I have the converter instance to convert the property from my model with converter.Convert(propValue, null, null, null)

1) Is there a way to do this with normal linq syntax. I found, that if the paramter array will have only a dictionary, it will be converted to an dict named extension in Dynamic.cs. Can this perhaps help? My actual linq is:

Creating Queryable:

```
var queryableList = collection.AsQueryable();
return queryableList.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), "Cast",
        new Type[] { itemType },
        queryableList.Expression));
```

Assign the filterString:

```
ParameterExpression[] parameterExpressions = new ParameterExpression[] {Expression.Parameter(Source.ItemType)};
ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(Source.ColumnInfoDict, parameterExpressions, filterText, new object[0]);

LambdaExpression lambda  =Expression.Lambda(parser.Parse(typeof(bool)), parameterExpressions);

var source = Queryable;
mQuery = source.Provider.CreateQuery(
         Expression.Call(
              typeof(Queryable), "Where",
              new Type[] { Source.ItemType },
              source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda))).Cast<object>();
```

2) The converter is also provided to the System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressonParser. I hoped to find a way to implement a Expression around the PropertyValue. But I don't find a way to construct a ExpressionCall, so when the filtering is done, the value from the model will be converted to the displayed value bevor doing the comparison.

I tried this where **left** is my PropertyExpression:

```
if(converter != null)
{
   Console.Out.WriteLine(left.NodeType);

   MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof (IValueConverter).GetMethod("Convert");
   Expression[] arguments = new Expression[] {left,null,null,null};
   left= Expression.Call(**converterExpression**, methodInfo,arguments);
}
```

But how can I construct the **converterExpression**? And will this work??

Comment: Why do you need to build a convert expression? Can't you just do the conversion by yourself before you create the constant?

Comment: No I can't, because if I will do it in my code. I have to parse the filterString to find the values, look for Identifier,...all what linq will do for me. And on the other hand it's ambiguous, if perhaps the converter will use ony a part of the property e.g. Bit 0..6 for one displayed value and the rest for another or so. So I think the only sure way is to convert the source. But in this way I see now another problem. The return value of IValueConverter is an object. And this is not excact for filtering. I need the type the converter deliver. In other case I will get a CastException from linkq.

Answer (score 0):

I found the follwoing solution. In System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressonParser I add the method:

```
private Expression ProvideValueConverter(Expression expr)
{
    Expression result = expr;
    if (mItemInfo != null)
    {
        IValueConverter converter = mItemInfo.Converter;
        if(converter != null)
        {

            Expression objTypedExpr =  Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(object));
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(IValueConverter).GetMethod("Convert");

            Expression[] arguments = new Expression[] { objTypedExpr, 
                                                        Expression.Default(typeof(Type)),
                                                        Expression.Default(typeof(object)),
                                                        Expression.Default(typeof(CultureInfo))

            };
            ConstantExpression converterExpression = Expression.Constant(converter);
            MethodCallExpression callExpression = Expression.Call(converterExpression, methodInfo, arguments);
            result = Expression.Convert(callExpression, mItemInfo.ItemType);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I call This method before returning the Property- oder FieldExpression:

```
Expression ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance) {
// some code.....
    else {
        MemberInfo member = FindPropertyOrField(type, id, instance == null);

        if (member == null)
            throw ParseError(errorPos, Res.UnknownPropertyOrField,
                             id, GetTypeName(type));
        MemberExpression me = member is PropertyInfo ? Expression.Property(instance, (PropertyInfo)member) : Expression.Field(instance, (FieldInfo)member);
        return ProvideValueConverter(me);
    }
}
```

mItemInfo is a Object filled outside DLINQ with apropriate Data. It is than passed as an parameter to DLINQ. The parameter is a dict with fieldNames-IColumnInfoObjects. In the ParseIdentifier mehod you can extract the IColumnInfoObject form the dict.